# How to correctly insert entries into `Json Array` within MySQL8?

Tags: mysql, json, join, inner-join

I am using `MySQL 8` and my table structure looks as below:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id INT, `group` VARCHAR(255), names JSON);
```

I am able to correctly insert records using the following `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES
(1100000, 'group1', '[{"name": "name1", "type": "user"}, {"name": "name2", "type": "user"}, {"name": "techDept", "type": "dept"}]');
```

The JSON format has two types - `user` and `dept`

Now, I have an array of `users and depts` which looks as below:

```
SET @userlist = '["user4", "user5"]';
SET @deptlist = '["dept4", "dept5"]';
```

For a new group `group2`, I want to insert all those users  and depts from within `userlist and deptlist array` into `t1 table` using a single query and I have written following query:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY_INSERT(JSON_OBJECT('name', @userlist , 'type', 'user'), ('name', @deptlist , 'type', 'gdl'));

Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'JSON_ARRAY_INSERT'
```